# How do I wait for page to load in selenium after click?

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm running a web scraping script, and I can't find anything reliable on allowing the page to reload when you click a link before the next line of code runs in the script. Below is what I'm currently doing, although it works, I know it's dependent on load times and it's definitely not efficient. Does anyone know if there's like a doThisWhenPageLoads() method I can use is selenium. I'm using node by the way in case that's important.

```
setTimeout(async () => {
        await driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="navigation"]/div[1]/ul/li[1]/div/div[1]/a')).click()
    }, 1500)
    // setTimeout(async () => {
        await driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, 10).findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="navigation"]/div[1]/ul/li[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a')).click()
    // }, 2500)
    setTimeout(async () => {
        await driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div/div[2]/div/header/div/div[3]/nav/ul/li[1]/div/div/ul/li[6]/a')).click()
    }, 4500)
    setTimeout(async () => {
        await driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div/div[2]/div/header/div/div[3]/nav/ul/li[1]/div/div[2]/ul/li[6]/ul/li[3]/a')).click()
    }, 6500)
    setTimeout(async () => {
        await driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div/div[2]/div/header/div/div[3]/nav/ul/li[1]/div/div[2]/ul/li[6]/ul/li[3]/ul/li[2]/a')).click()
    }, 8500)
    setTimeout(async () => {
        const target = await driver.findElements(By.xpath('//ul[contains(@class, "product-list")]/li'))

        let arr = await target.map(async (x, index) => {
            let title = await x.findElement(By.xpath(`//li[${index + 1}]/div/div/div/div/div/div`)).getText()
            let price = await x.findElement(By.xpath(`//li[${index + 1}]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div/div`)).getText()
            let pricePer100ml = await x.findElement(By.xpath(`//li[${index + 1}]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div/div[2]`)).getText()
            let ok = { title, price, pricePer100ml }
            console.log(ok)
            return ok
        })
        console.log(arr)
    }, 13500)
```

Comment: If it's a standard page load, Selenium already waits (for PageReady state) by default.  If the click generates a javascript DOM update instead, you need to use a webdriverwait:  https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_WebDriverWait.htm

Answer (score 0):

Well Selenium already waits if page loads on button clicks. But there are some cases where you may need to wait and Selenium don't wait. You can do this by JavaScript in those cases.

I haven't used Selenium with JavaScript but here is a C# implementation which you can easily implement in JavaScript as per your requirements.

```
private void pageLoad(ChromeDriver driver)
{
    IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20));
    wait.Until(wd => js.ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").ToString() == "complete");
}
```

document.readyState will return "complete" when the page loads completely. So, IJavaScriptExecutor is a class provided by Selenium which allows us to execute JavaScript code in browsers console. You need to check how you can use IJavaScriptExecutor in JavaScript.

This function will wait for 20 seconds. However you can also wait forever until the page loads completely by using while loop and check if the readyState complete or not.